# How to create an API using Laravel 4

Tags: php, api, laravel-4

I have a question about how to create or build a simple API using laravel PHP framework.
I have searched a lot in the net, but dont get a proper answer.
Can anyone help me, Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680396/how-to-build-a-rest-api-in-laravel-4-and-add-users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680396/how-to-build-a-rest-api-in-laravel-4-and-add-users)

Comment: Here is a [great tutorial](https://medium.com/laravel-4/c643022433ad), another tutorial from [tutsplus](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/laravel-4-a-start-at-a-restful-api-updated--net-29785)

Comment: @Technoknol - Is REST API and ordinary API are same?

Comment: @Amesh - basically yes, they are the same. A REST API is just a way to build the API to confirm to some standards around urls etc.

Comment: @Amesh Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10596128/2219158

Comment: Check the dingo/api package for creating new API, if you don't want to build a lot of things from scratch. https://github.com/dingo/api

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to just don't care about the views. For example:

In your UsersController.php

```
public function show($id) {
    $users = User::all();
    return $users;
}
```

Route.php

```
Route::get('/api/users', 'UsersController@show');
```

You'll then get a json object as response.

Then you can build it up with resources to get post, put etc to work. Read more in the laravel documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/routing

Laracasts has an entire series for building APIs: https://laracasts.com/series/incremental-api-development